# Interpret Google AutoML Online Prediction Results

Tags: google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-automl-nl

We are using [Google AutoML](https://cloud.google.com/automl/) with Tables using input as CSV files. We have imported data , linked all schema with nullable columns and train model and then deployed and used the online prediction to predict value of one column.

Column we targeted has values min-max ( 44 - 263).

When we deployed and ran online-prediction it return values like this

Prediction result

```
0.49457597732543945
```

95% prediction interval

```
[-8.209495544433594, 0.9892584085464478]
```

Most of the resultset is in above format. How can we convert it to values in range of (44-263). Didn't find much documentation online on the same.

Looking for documentation reference and interpretation along with interpretation of 95% prediction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually to clarify (I'm the PM of AutoML Tables)--

AutoML Tables **does not** do any normalization of the predicted values for your label data, so if you expect your label data to have a distribution of min/max 44-263, then the output predictions should also be in that range. Two possibilities would make it significantly different:

1) You selected the wrong label column

2) Your input features for this prediction are dramatically different than what was seen in the training data used.

Please feel free to reach out to cloud-automl-tables-discuss@googlegroups.com if you'd like us to help debug further

Comment: @TinYunHo - I have send email to mentioned email id above.

Comment: changing batch parameters now gives us results in expected format. However not sure about its accuracy; that's a different question though